# How to flag column with condition other field and period date in sql DB2?

Tags: sql, db2, case

I have the following table:

```
TABLE1
AREA_CODE|ITEM_CODE|EXP_DATE|STATUS
ABC|"16060715143928060544ii|2019-05-3|02
DEF|1606071514392806054JJ|2018-05-24|03
GHI|160607151439280605LL|2017-12-12|25
JKL|1606071545555928060MM|2018-07-20|02
```

I want to achieve the result which selects all field on TABLE1 and new columns containing flags based on (EXP_DATE that belong to periods '2017-12-01' until '2018-12-31') and (less than period) will be filled same as the initial value of the STATUS column, IF not included will be filled '25'. Ie

```
AREA_CODE|ITEM_CODE|EXP_DATE|STATUS|STATUS_OPR
ABC|16060715143928060544ii|2019-05-3|02|25
DEF|1606071514392806054JJ|2018-05-24|03|03
GHI|160607151439280605LL|2017-12-12|25|25
JKL|1606071545555928060MM|2018-07-20|02|02
```

How can I achieve this using CASE WHEN? I have done as follows but it is not working.

```
SELECT AREA_CODE, ITEM_CODE, EXP_DATE, STATUS,
CASE
WHEN EXP_DATE BETWEEN '2017-12-01' AND '2018-12-31' THEN '25'
ELSE STATUS
END AS STATUS_OPR
FROM TABLE1;
```

Can someone help with the query? Thank you before.

Comment: And what is the issue with this query? error? wrong result?

Comment: thank you @tejash. the query can run, but for result is not as expected. this result AREA_CODE|ITEM_CODE|EXP_DATE|STATUS|STATUS_OPR ABC|16060715143928060544ii|2019-05-3|02|02 DEF|1606071514392806054JJ|2018-05-24|03|- GHI|160607151439280605LL|2017-12-12|25|- JKL|1606071545555928060MM|2018-07-20|02|-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank guys for help me.

This case is finished, before my logic was wrong. with SQL below: 
`SELECT AREA_CODE, ITEM_CODE, EXP_DATE, STATUS, CASE WHEN (STATUS <> '25') AND (EXP_DATE > '2018-12-31') THEN '25' ELSE STATUS END AS STATUS_OPR FROM TABLE1;`

Answer (score 0):

you need to cast the dates so your date condition will work.

```
SELECT AREA_CODE, ITEM_CODE, EXP_DATE, STATUS,
CASE
WHEN (EXP_DATE >=DATE('2017-12-01') AND EXP_DATE <= DATE('2018-12-31')) THEN '25'
ELSE STATUS
END AS STATUS_OPR
FROM TABLE1;
```

Comment: '2018-12-31' without using `DATE` function is considered as a date.

Comment: Thank you @metal for your help. I have tried, but wrong result.

AREA_CODE|ITEM_CODE|EXP_DATE|STATUS|STATUS_OPR
ABC|16060715143928060544ii|2019-05-3|02|02
DEF|1606071514392806054JJ|2018-05-24|03|-
GHI|160607151439280605LL|2017-12-12|25|-
JKL|1606071545555928060MM|2018-07-20|02|-

Answer (score 0):

Your query is perfectly fine, but I think your `EXP_DATE` column is not a `date` data type.

You need to convert it to date (using `TO_DATE` function) while using it in your case expression.

Cheers!!

Comment: is anyone have any other idea for this case?

Comment: This is very simple case. You can use to_date as suggested in answer. You have saved date data type in character column so this is the solution.